# Error Transporting a View From Oracle to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, oracle, porting

I'm migrating somebody else's View from an Oracle DB to a Mysql DB. I'm not familiar with the `table(cast(multiset()))` operator and so I have no clue how to transpose it to MySql

The part of the code that gives me an error is the following:

```
SELECT csCOUNTRY.ID,  csCOUNTRY.COUNTRY_ID,
      trim(regexp_substr(COUNTRY_ID, '[^;]+', 1, levels.column_value)) AS COUNTRY_ID_2  
FROM table_study csCOUNTRY, 
       table(
           cast(
           multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (REGEXP_REPLACE(COUNTRY_ID, '[^;]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)
       ) 
           levels)
```

The error I recive is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <=
>   length (REGEXP_R' at line 255

How can I transpose it correctly?

Comment: I would start by checking the Oracle manual to find out what `multiset()` does, then all the other bits you dont understand

Comment: i've looked what multiset and table do, but i can't find an equivalent in mySql (in which i'm a total novice), that's why i need some advices for this porting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multicast converts rows into a single table-type. Oracle table's column type can be standard Oracle SQL Types(number, char, varchar2) or user defined table types.

But, here the cast and multicast operator is redundant.
Below query should give same result :

```
SELECT csCOUNTRY.ID,  csCOUNTRY.COUNTRY_ID,
      trim(regexp_substr(COUNTRY_ID, '[^;]+', 1, levels.lvl)) AS COUNTRY_ID_2  
FROM table_study csCOUNTRY, 
     (select level lvl 
        from dual 
     connect by  level <= length (REGEXP_REPLACE(COUNTRY_ID, '[^;]+'))) levels
```

Comment: I had still problems with Connect By, but i could manage it so your answer was very helpuful. Thank you

Comment: The from dual connect by clause in oracle is used to generate rows. Its also used for data explosion queries (which is what is happening here)